# How to send the image ng-style value in a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting image url from the service. I need to send again the same url in another function as a parameter.

```html
<div class="modalContainer" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + prefixVal + completiondetail.IDProofURL + toaken +')'}">

                
</div>
```

```html
<input type="button" name="save" ng-click="saveData()" value="save">
```

I have a save button. I need to pass that image url in inside ng-click function saveData() as a parameter. How can I send this?

Comment: You don't need to pass it to ng-click, since it's already in your JS. The URL is in your service, so just call `saveData(url)` from your service.

Comment: A simple answer would be to use `saveData({{selectedMeal.url}})`, but i guess it's the first thing you have tried? If this didn't work, it means that we need more precisions: are these 2 parts of code in different views? Have acces to the same controller(s)? etc

Comment: I tried this. But its not working

Comment: Call `saveData(prefixVal + completiondetail.IDProofURL + toaken)`

Answer (score 0):

Try passing url like this,

```
<input type="button" name="save" ng-click="saveData(selectedMeal.url)" value="save">
```

In your controller,

```
$scope.saveData = function(url){
  // url = image url
}
```